# how to catch error of an asyn function call

Tags: async-await, axios, try-catch, vuejs3, pinia

I don't succeed catching the error that a async function returns. Using Vuejs 3 with a pinia store, althought I don't think that this is specific to vue or pinia.

In a `pinia store` I have this function:

```js
const getAccount = async(id, month, year) => {
  try {
    getData.defaults.headers.common['__authorization__'] = UserStore.jwt
    const response = await getData.get(`/use/b/comptes/${id}/${month}/${year}`)
    if (response.status === 200) {              
      // update store state and:
      return true
    }
    return false
  } catch (error) {
    // => this gets correctly executed when the server responds with 409
    // console.error(`erreur catch : ${error.response.data.error}`)
    return error.response.data
  }
}
```

I'm calling this function from a component, like so:

```js
watchEffect(() => {
  if (route.name === 'comptes') {
    getAccount( compte.value.id, route.params.month, route.params.year )
    .then(result => { console.log('result', result.error) })
    .catch(err => { 
      // this never gets executed, including when server returns a 409
      console.log('err', err)
      })
    }
  })
```

In other words: in the function call, only the `then` block gets executed, not the catch.

How do I catch the error of the first function?

Comment: Not sure that mixing `async/await` and `.then` is helping. Please try to use `async/await` everywhere.

Comment: When you do `try/catch` in `getAccount` you actually handled the error and swallow it. So when the server returns an error it will show in `getAccount().then()`. If you want to catch the error one more time, you need to explicitly throw it in the catch statement `throw error.response.data `

Comment: @Duannx : exactly the solution. Though to learn javascript when coming from ruby. Thanks.